# Non-orientable 1-dimensional (non-hausdorff) manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, separation-axioms, orientation

Is there any nice example of a 1-dimensional non-hausdorff manifold that is not oriented? I have tried the line with two origins, but maybe something more exotic is needed?

Answer (score 14):

How about the quotient of the real line by the relation $x\sim y$ iff $x=-y$ and $|x|>1$?  It looks sort of like this:

[image]

(The two black dots are the equivalence classes of $+1$ and $-1$.)

Comment: why is this non-orientable??

Comment: Intuitively, if your orient the left-hand loop in the clockwise direction, then approaching from above forces the right-hand ray to be oriented to the right, while approaching from below forces it to be oriented to the left.  You can turn this into a rigorous argument by covering the space with two coordinate charts (images of $(-1,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,1)$ in the quotient space), and considering the various possibilities for choices of orientations on the two components of the overlap.

Comment: If the condition is $|x|\geq1$ instead of $|x|>1$, is the space Hausdorff?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, then it's just homeomorphic to a circle with a whisker attached. Since that's realizable as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$, it's Hausdorff.

Comment: Thank you! But then isn't all 1D Housdorff manifold orientable?

Comment: @Alex: yes, every 1-dimensional (Hausdorff) manifold is orientable.

Comment: @Alex That space (with $|x| \ge 1$) would not be a manifold, since it is not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ at (the equivalence class of) 1.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more technical construction:

Let $X = (0, 2]$ with a basis consisting of open intervals in $(0, 2)$ as well as subsets of the form $(1 - \epsilon, 1) \cup (2 - \epsilon, 2]$ for $\epsilon > 0$.

This space is clearly locally Euclidean for $x \in X - \{2\}$. For $2$, use the following homeomorphism from $V = (1 - \epsilon, 1) \cup (2 - \epsilon, 2]$ onto the open interval $(1 - \epsilon, 1 + \epsilon)$ in $\Bbb R$:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x &: x \in (1 - \epsilon, 1) \\
3 - x &: x \in (2 - \epsilon, 2]
\end{cases}
$$

The points $1$ and $2$ have no disjoint neighborhoods, so $X$ is not Hausdorff. $X$ is second countable, since it has a basis consisting of open sets with rational end points.

Finally, $X$ is non-orientable. One possible generator for $H_1(V, V - \{2\})$ is the following singular $1$-simplex:
$$
\tau(t) = \begin{cases}
1 - \dfrac{\epsilon}{2} + t\epsilon &: t \in \left[0, \dfrac{1}{2}\right) \\
2 - \left(t - \dfrac{1}{2}\right)\epsilon &: t \in \left[\dfrac{1}{2}, 1\right]
\end{cases}
$$

No matter what orientation you choose for $(0, 2)$, $\tau$ cannot be compatible with it. Verify this! This is also true for the other generator of $H_1(V, V - \{2\})$.